# Int Value in C# does not match with SQL count() value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to pass a value from my SQL query count() to c# int Tech_Count but it's displaying different.  If I only run the query count, it return 3 but in c#, it's showing -1.  Here's my code.

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\anthonyhau\Documents\Lawn Mower\LawnMowerDatabase\LawnMowerDatabase\Database1.mdf");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Tech set Customer_Count = (select IdAndCnt.cnt from (select Tech_Id,count (Tech_id) as cnt from Customers group by Tech_Id ) as IdAndCnt where Tech.Tech_Id = IdAndCnt.Tech_Id)", con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers (First_Name, Last_Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Phone, Date_Started) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "', '" + textBox7.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')", con);
        SqlCommand techcnt = new SqlCommand("Select count(Tech_Id) From Tech", con);

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int Tech_Count = techcnt.ExecuteNonQuery();

        textBox8.Text = Tech_Count.ToString();


        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use ExecuteScalar instead of executenonquery and it will solve your problem.

int Tech_Count = (int)techcnt.ExecuteScalar();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ExecuteNonQuery` does not return the count like that for `SELECT` statements:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ExecuteNonQuery if you are in fact executing a query?? Objects in classes are pretty self explanatory. ExecuteNonQuery is used for update,deletes and inserts so it returns the affected rows. Try this on for size:

```
SqlCommand techcnt = new SqlCommand("Select @count:=count(Tech_Id) From Tech", con);
techcnt.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
techcnt.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
techcnt.ExecuteScalar();
textBox8.Text = techcnt.Parameters["@count"].Value.ToString();
```

or something shorter like this:

```
SqlCommand techcnt = new SqlCommand("Select count(Tech_Id) From Tech", con);

textBox8.Text = techcnt.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```